# Get the most detail from Exim log debug output for pipe commands

Tags: containers, podman, exim

How do you see the most detail from Exim's output?

I'm specifically trying to debug a pipe/external command on a Red Hat based OS.

I've got a good amount of [Exim debug logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/574909/how-to-log-full-output-of-exim-pipe-command/1132320), but it doesn't seem to be enough.

Our exim transport works fine with our integration of Mailman2, but Mailman3 required us to implement it with a rootless container. I'm unclear what part of the process allows them to work, or how to see the commands fail more than I already do.

Our old, working exim.conf transport:

```
mailman_virtual_transport:
    driver = pipe
    command = /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/mail/mailman \
              '${if def:local_part_suffix \
                    {${sg{$local_part_suffix}{-(\\w+)(\\+.*)?}{\$1}}} \
                    {post}}' \
              ${perl{untaint}{${lc:$local_part}_${lc:$domain}}}
    current_directory = /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman
    home_directory = /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman
    user = mailman
    group = mailman
```

We're unable to use the [Docker-suggested Exim transport definition](https://github.com/maxking/docker-mailman/blob/main/core/assets/exim/55_mm3_transport) due to our non-root security needs:

```
mailman3_transport:
  driver = smtp
  protocol = lmtp
  allow_localhost
  hosts = localhost
  port = MM3_LMTP_PORT
  rcpt_include_affixes = true
```

So we're using this transport using driver pipe:

```
mailman3_virtual_transport:
    driver = pipe
    command = /usr/bin/podman exec -i mailman-core /usr/bin/mailman --run-as-root \
              '${if def:local_part_suffix \
                    {${sg{$local_part_suffix}{-(\\w+)(\\+.*)?}{\$1}}} \
                    {inject}}' \
              '-f' '-' \
              ${perl{untaint}{${lc:$local_part}\@${lc:$domain}}}
    user = MM3_GID
    group = MM3_UID
```

It works fine for regular mailing list sending of email (inject -f - listname), but does not work for the majordomo-like aliases, which worked fine in our Mailman2 usage, e.g. an alias file containing:

```
...
m3listmailman3-subscribe@mailman3.test: "|/usr/bin/podman exec -i -t mailman-core mailman --run-as-root subscribe m3mailman3_mailman3.test"
...
*: mailman3
```

So the command that allows mail to be successfully transferred is this:

```
/usr/bin/podman exec -i mailman-core /usr/bin/mailman --run-as-root inject -f - m3list-join@mailman3.test
```

The output of a successfull normal send-email-to-the-list command:

```
557025 direct command after expansion:
557025   argv[0] = '/usr/bin/podman'
557025   argv[1] = 'exec'
557025   argv[2] = '-i'
557025   argv[3] = 'mailman-core'
557025   argv[4] = '/usr/bin/mailman'
557025   argv[5] = '--run-as-root'
557025   argv[6] = 'inject'
557025   argv[7] = '-f'
557025   argv[8] = '-'
557025   argv[9] = 'm3list@mailman3.test'
557025 delivery-local forking for pipe-tpt-cmd
557025 delivery-local forked for pipe-tpt-cmd: 557026
557025 delivery-local forking for pipe-tpt-output
557025 delivery-local forked for pipe-tpt-output: 557027
557025 Writing message to pipe
557025 writing data block fd=9 size=54 timeout=3600
557025 cannot use sendfile for body: spoolfile not wireformat
557025 writing data block fd=9 size=610 timeout=3600
557025 writing data block fd=9 size=1 timeout=3600
557027 postfork: pipe-tpt-output
557027 set_process_info: 557027 reading output from |/usr/bin/podman exec -i mailman-core /usr/bin/mailman --run-as-root '${if def:local_part_suffix {${sg{$local_part_suffix}{-(\\w+)(\\+.*)?}{\$1}}} {inject}}' '-f' '-' ${perl{untaint}{${lc:$local_part}\@${lc:$domain}}}
557026 postfork: pipe-tpt-cmd
557020 search_tidyup called
557020 SMTP>>(close on process exit)
557020 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exim pid=557020 (daemon-accept) terminating with rc=0 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
555764 child 557020 ended: status=0x0
555764   normal exit, 0
555764 0 SMTP accept processes now running
555764 Listening...
557025 mailman3_virtual_transport transport yielded 0
557025 search_tidyup called
557022 journalling m3list@mailman3.test
557022 mailman3_virtual_transport transport returned OK for m3list@mailman3.test
557022 post-process m3list@mailman3.test (0)
557022 m3list@mailman3.test delivered
557022 LOG: MAIN
557022   => m3list <m3list@mailman3.test> R=mailman3_router T=mailman3_virtual_transport
557022 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> deliveries are done >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

However, when attempting the aliases, it doesn't work.  E.g., trying:

```
/usr/bin/podman exec -i mailman-core /usr/bin/mailman --run-as-root inject -f - m3list-join@mailman3.test
```

Results:

```
2023-06-07 08:57:47 1q6tfX-002e31-2G <= notamember2@mailman3.test H=localhost (10-2-66-113.cprapid.com) [127.0.0.1]:55270 P=esmtpa A=dovecot_login:notamember2@mailman3.test S=1237 id=e6f7197f8873a2e9ed68ce2f59aca60a@mailman3.test T="Re: subscribe" for m3list-join@mailman3.test
2023-06-07 08:57:49 1q6tfX-002e31-2G ** m3list@mailman3.test <m3list-join@mailman3.test> R=mailman3_virtual_router_suffixed T=mailman3_virtual_transport: Child process of mailman3_virtual_transport transport returned 2 from command: /usr/bin/podman
2023-06-07 08:57:49 1q6tfX-002e31-2G Completed
```

```
08:57:47 630607 direct command after expansion:
08:57:47 630607   argv[0] = '/usr/bin/podman'
08:57:47 630607   argv[1] = 'exec'
08:57:47 630607   argv[2] = '-i'
08:57:47 630607   argv[3] = 'mailman-core'
08:57:47 630607   argv[4] = '/usr/bin/mailman'
08:57:47 630607   argv[5] = '--run-as-root'
08:57:47 630607   argv[6] = 'inject'
08:57:47 630607   argv[7] = '-f'
08:57:47 630607   argv[8] = '-'
08:57:47 630607   argv[9] = 'm3list-join@mailman3.test'

08:57:47 630607 delivery-local forking for pipe-tpt-cmd
08:57:47 630607 delivery-local forked for pipe-tpt-cmd: 630608
08:57:47 630607 delivery-local forking for pipe-tpt-output
08:57:47 630607 delivery-local forked for pipe-tpt-output: 630609
08:57:47 630607 Writing message to pipe
08:57:47 630607  ╭considering: From ${if def:return_path{$return_path}{MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ├───────text: From
08:57:47 630607  ├considering: ${if def:return_path{$return_path}{MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ├──condition: def:return_path
08:57:47 630607  ├─────result: true
08:57:47 630607   ╭considering: $return_path}{MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607   ├considering: }{MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607   ├──expanding: $return_path
08:57:47 630607   ╰─────result: notamember2@mailman3.test
08:57:47 630607              ╰──(tainted)
08:57:47 630607   ╭───scanning: MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607   ├───────text: MAILER-DAEMON
08:57:47 630607   ├───scanning: }} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607   ├──expanding: MAILER-DAEMON
08:57:47 630607   ├─────result: MAILER-DAEMON
08:57:47 630607   ╰───skipping: result is not used
08:57:47 630607  ├───item-res: notamember2@mailman3.test
08:57:47 630607             ╰──(tainted)
08:57:47 630607  ├considering:  ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ├───────text:
08:57:47 630607  ├considering: ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ├considering:
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ├───────text:
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ├──expanding: From ${if def:return_path{$return_path}{MAILER-DAEMON}} ${tod_bsdinbox}
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607  ╰─────result: From notamember2@mailman3.test Wed Jun 07 08:57:47 2023
08:57:47 630607
08:57:47 630607             ╰──(tainted)
08:57:47 630607 writing data block fd=9 size=56 timeout=3600
08:57:47 630607 cannot use sendfile for body: spoolfile not wireformat
08:57:47 630607 writing data block fd=9 size=1237 timeout=3600
08:57:47 630607 writing data block fd=9 size=1 timeout=3600
08:57:47 630608 postfork: pipe-tpt-cmd
08:57:47 630609 postfork: pipe-tpt-output
08:57:47 630609 set_process_info: 630609 reading output from |/usr/bin/podman exec -i mailman-core /usr/bin/mailman --run-as-root 'inject' '-f' '-' ${perl{untaint}{${lc:$local_part$local_part_suffix}\@${lc:$domain}}}
08:57:47 630603 search_tidyup called
08:57:47 630603 SMTP>>(close on process exit)
08:57:47 630603 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exim pid=630603 (daemon-accept) terminating with rc=0 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
08:57:47 630521 child 630603 ended: status=0x0
08:57:47 630521   normal exit, 0
08:57:47 630521 0 SMTP accept processes now running
08:57:47 630521 Listening...
08:57:49 630607 mailman3_virtual_transport transport yielded 2
08:57:49 630607 search_tidyup called
08:57:49 630604 mailman3_virtual_transport transport returned FAIL for m3list-join@mailman3.test
08:57:49 630604 post-process m3list-join@mailman3.test (2)
08:57:49 630604 LOG: MAIN
08:57:49 630604   ** m3list@mailman3.test <m3list-join@mailman3.test> R=mailman3_virtual_router_suffixed T=mailman3_virtual_transport: Child process of mailman3_virtual_transport transport returned 2 from command: /usr/bin/podman
08:57:49 630604 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> deliveries are done >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

How do I see more output from the command?  Currently the only error I can see is this, and I'm not sure how I'd reproduce the command to see it working or not working or give more output:

```
Child process of mailman3_virtual_transport transport returned 2 from command: /usr/bin/podman
```

If I try to run the line on it's own, it hangs. I don't see how Exim sends the message:

```
mailman:/opt/mailman# /usr/bin/mailman --run-as-root join -f - m3list@mailman3.test
^C
Aborted!
mailman:/opt/mailman#
```